# Combining / uniting two strings in Scala

Tags: scala

What would be the best way to combine `"__L_"` and `"_E__"` to `"_EL_"` in Scala?

I don't want to use `if` and `for` commands.

Comment: `def combine(x: String, y: String) = "EL"`.  But seriously, your problem is severely underspecified.

Comment: "_E".stripPrefix("_")`+ `"L_".stripSuffix("_")

Comment: Sorry, it seems my post was edited automatically or somehow, and it doesn't show up as it should. I was looking for a solution for a problem where you have two strings that both contain "hidden letters" as "-". Let's say, as an original word you have "--L-" and as a new word "-E--". I'm trying to combine these to words into "-EL-". And yes, I'm looking for a general case which might underspecify the problem. This was also my first post, so it might take a couple of posts to get familiar with all the standards and requirements.

Comment: @JulleImmonen you should add that description to the question body

Comment: @JulleImmonen what if both symbols are defined at specific position?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean. Are you looking to concatenate two strings, without the last character of the first and the first character of the second? Or do you need to check that  last/first characters are from some set of "hidden letters"? Or that they match? Really, you've not explained your problem yet.

Comment: Also, why not use if/for? Yo can always "hide" them by defining a function if you object to their appearance...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I guess it's homework restriction

Comment: Epic -1 combo, thanks to @TheArchetypalPaul

Comment: @JulleImmonen, please clarify the problem!

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
def combine(xs: String, ys: String): String = 
  (xs zip ys).map {
    case ('_', y) => y
    case (x, _) => x 
  }.mkString("")
```

The only thing that is not really nice about this is how to get back from a collection (IndexedSeq[Char]) to a string. An alternative is to use the String constructor that takes an Array[Char]. That would probably be more efficient.

Note that zip will work for strings of different length, but the result will be the size of the shorter string. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Sorry it's my accidental misclick downvote. If you will do some minor edit to your answer I will able to remove it.

Comment: My downvote wasn't accidental  :) `combine("_E_", "_L_")                           //> res0: String = _E_` is not a desirable outcome

Comment: What would be the desirable outcome in that case?

Comment: "-EL-". The OP even gives that as an example in a comment (using`-`, not `_` because _ gets eaten by the markdown)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Your donwvote should have been accidental. The words from example have 4 chars.

Comment: @Nebril, and in the original post., but markdown removes them. I'll remove the downvote if the answer gets edited (i'm locked until the).

Answer (score 2):

```
def zipStrings(first: String,
               second: String,
               comb: (Char, Char) => String = (f, _) => f.toString, 
               placeholder: Char = '_') =
  first.zipAll(second, '_', '_').map {
  case (c, `placeholder`) => c
  case (`placeholder`, c) => c
  case (f, s) => comb(f, s)
}.mkString
```

that prioritises characters from first over second by default

```
zipStrings("__A", "X_CD") // yields "X_AD"

zipStrings("A__YY", "BXXXX", (f, s) => s"($f|$s)") // yields "(A|B)XX(Y|X)(Y|X)"
```

For you original strings:

```
zipStrings("L_", "_E")  // yield "LE"

zipStrings("--L-", "-E--", placeholder = '-') // yields "-EL-"
```

Comment: It would be good to give examples for the OP's two test cases `zipStrings("E_", "_L")                            //> res0: String = EL` works, but
`zipStrings("_E_", "_L_")                          //> res1: String = _E_` doesn't. Maybe I'm invoking it incorrectly though.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul You misreaded the second example it's "--L-" and "-E--" =>  "-EL-".

Comment: yes, I missed that. But now I think it's really unclear what the requirement is. Reversed the downvote, but I think the various answers (including mine) show the futility of trying to guess what the OP meant...

Comment: This reminds me of a thing I saw sometime about overcomplicated solutions: http://synflood.at/blog/index.php?/archives/744-Evolution-of-a-C++-Programmer.html :)